# Why do I get different results when UPDATE page and click the link on OpenShift?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications, openshift

[Here is the link to try](http://trs1509-sergeylotvin.rhcloud.com/) The problem is: I got different results when UPDATE or when click link to page.But all works fine on localhost.

My idea for now is that there is mapping problem. `Index` link has code:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/actDBTestConn">Index</a>
```

where `actDBTestConn` in web.xml mapped to servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DBTestConn</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>myServlets.DBTestConn</servlet-class>        
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DBTestConn</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/actDBTestConn</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and Tomcat on OpenShift for some reason doesn't get this mapping. But why UPDATE button works, I have no idea. 
Using `rhc` and `tail_all` command I can see the log. So I see that click to link do not call the `myServlets.DBTestConnand` and its `doGet` method while UPDATE button do. why?
Help to understand, please!

Answer (score 1):

All troubles gone away just after 2 days. I'm not sure, but looks like it was **OpenShift** specifics. Maybe some troubles with cache.